# Remove quotes from Json Object when there is no specific model to map against

Tags: java, json

I have a Json object received from an external client.

The existing code currently map it to type Object instead of a custom Object type.

Can't change this part of code thus need to work with type Object.

When we receive this Json object it ends up in following format (as a Json String) with unneeded quotes.

```
"{\"data\": null, \"sample\": null, \"load\": {\"id\": 111, \"schema\": null}}"
```

Need it to be as follows (Inserting this as a JsonB into a database):

```
{"data": null, "sample": null, "load": {"id": 111, "schema": null}}
```

I can't just use Jackson's ObjectMapper to resolve this since the type is Object instead of a custom model class.

I could use Regex and replace all the quotes.

But looking for suggestions for a better elegant solution than Regex. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: How do you get that quotes-full string? 
Is this a `.toString()`? 
If so, you can change the format of your toString to fit the json format. Are you using eclipse?

Comment: @BarHoshen Using Intellij. It is not a toString(), at least not directly. It ends up in this format after going through kafka where the correct 2nd version above is stored there in metadata and when we retrieve it from Kafka, it ends up in this String format.

Comment: I dont know intellij well and never worked with kafka, but the string you currently have is  a `.toString()` code. It's hard to understand your exact situation ( = can't see why you can't create a custom Object) but i would try to  create a wrapper class and edit it's toString

Comment: @BarHoshen Can't do that cos the above json format differs and has 12 variations. Example: Above example has "data" key. Another value might come in and may not have "data" key and instead "something_else" key. Wouldn't want to override toString() for this. If that's the only route, would stick to Regex solution.

Comment: Ok then yeah, seems like editing the string with regex would be best workaround... But i bet the original issue is some weird kafka behavior that you should be able to fix. Consider asking this question again with the Kafka tag.
Good luck and sorry i couldnt be of much help!

Comment: Wait, realized something - 
This string is java syntax. If you simply create a string with this text it will comeout formatted as you want.


`  String h = "{\"data\": null, \"sample\": null, \"load\": {\"id\": 111, \"schema\": null}}";
  System.out.println(h);
 
`

Comment: @BarHoshen Thanks. That does clear up the unneeded quotes in the String. Still keeps the start and end quotes though. Guess could subString those out.